# Charger says 5-cell li-ion battery at 17.7 volt OCV dead or deeply discharged, what could the cause be?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, low-battery

I have a lawnmower with two lithium-ion batteries. I charged them after sitting during the winter period. One battery charged happily to 19.15 volt open circuit voltage (OCV), whereas the other had the charger flashing both of its lights. I measured the other battery after trying to charge it for an hour and it had 17.7 volt OCV. I let it rest for another hour, and it still has 17.7 volt OCV.

The battery charger user manual specifies that if the charger flashes both of its lights, either the battery is dead beyond repair or deeply discharged. It won't tell which of these two conditions is true. Apparently it tries to rejuvenate the battery by charging it extremely slowly, so slowly that it does not heat at all.

I'm somewhat surprised by a battery having 17.7 volt OCV being proclaimed as dead or deeply discharged.

What could the cause be?

The fully charged battery has 19.15 V / 5 = 3.83 V voltage per cell.

The dead battery has 17.7 V / 5 = 3.54 V voltage per cell. To me, this does not seem to be beyond repair.

Is it possible that the 17.7 V battery has one bad cell and four good ones? If it's possible it has one bad cell and four good, what are the chances of rejuvenating it by trying to charge it slowly for many hours?

I cannot access the individual cells without dismantling the battery. It only allows me to access two terminals at the ends of the chain.

Comment: It seems likely that one of the cells has shorted or otherwise died, yes. I'll leave an actual answer to someone who knows more, though.

Comment: @Hearth; there could be a cell that is *open* circuit. Most charge controllers I have worked with will flag a fault if no (or tiny) current flows. Keep in mind that a DMM has a rather large input impedance so only a few uA need to flow to get a measurement.

Comment: @PeterSmith You may be right. I tried to get some current to flow through two 12V 55W light bulbs in series and saw absolutely no current. Probably nearly open circuit, yes. So I assume I'll just have to discard that battery.